# NeuralNetworks Inputs units

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics

I want to know if is it possible to build a neural network with inputs with different units.

For example, can I build a neural network using as inputs temperatures and percentage of a chemical product?

If not, is it possible to split a neural network into different neural networks and combine the results or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In machine learning, there's no such thing as "units". Units are a physical concept, whereas machine learning techniques are pure mathematical abstractions. They see all input variables as just "some number". Any physical interpretation of what that number represents is outside the scope of the ML method you're using.

Now, that doesn't mean you can't have a physical interpretation of the quantity going into the ML algorithm. One way to square the fact that these are physical quantities but the thing going into the ML method is a number is to divide your quantity by one "unit" of the physical metric in question.

For example, suppose one of your inputs is temperature, $T$, and another is length, $L$. As we know, the quantity $T + L$ is not defined, and just generally makes no sense. Yet neural networks would do this operation if $T$ and $L$ were inputs. However, the operation $T/T_0 + L/L_0$ makes perfect sense, and is totally viable if $T_0$ is a temperature and $L_0$ is a length.

Physical quantities are not numbers. Saying something like "I am 3 tall" makes no sense. But we can say "I am 3 feet tall". This is essentially saying that $H = 3 \cdot H_0$ where $H$ is my height and $H_0$ is one foot. Or, rearranging, $H / H_0 = 3.$

Physical inputs to ML algorithms should always be interpreted as the physical quantity, divided by one unit of whatever units you're measuring it in. So if your input is temperature in Kelvin, your input is $T/T_0$ where $T_0$ is one Kelvin. If it's temperature in Celcius, then it's $(T + T_c) / T_0$ where $T_c$ is $273.15$ Kelvin. If, on the other hand, you want to standardize it to have $0$ mean and $1$ standard deviation then it will be $(\frac{T}{T_0} - \bar{T}) / S$ where $\bar{T}$ is the mean of $T / T_0$ and $S$ is the standard deviation of $T / T_0.$

Answer (score 0):

Both of your options are possible. You can feed a NN with inputs in different units, and it should be able to learn how to transform them, however, especially if you are using regularizers you should scale your inputs to have `mean = 0`  and `standard deviation = 1`, it has been proven to make learning faster and more effective.

L2 regularizer for example tries to make weights smaller, meaning that if you have meters and centimeters in two inputs variables, the meters should get larger weights (to convert it to comparable units), since, a priori, the may have the same importance, however L2 regularizer will penalize big weights, this could be, and probably will be a problem for your NN, just scale the inputs, it is not a big deal and everything will work better.

You may do this by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation by hand or just using some package [Sklearn Standard Scaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html).

You could build a NN that takes as inputs the output of 2 NN but I would not advise you to do that in this case.

Comment: How is that related to regularizers?

Comment: L2 regularizer tries to make large coefficients smaller, if you have two inputs one in meters and one in centimeters the latter one will be penalized, even if it is, in fact, more meaningful for the output variable

Comment: Maybe state in the answer that you mean L* regularizers. Others, like dropout, have little to do with that. Also, in your example, I suppose the first would be penalized more (small units->larger numbers->smaller weights->smaller penalty). Plus it assumes they have same range and different units.

Comment: oh yeah, i put it upside down, thanks for pointing it out, i will make it clear in my answer